# How to fix "Failed identify data 0:no magic files loaded" error for MIME type in PHP?

Tags: php

I have tried both the options:

1. mime_content_type function

   ```
   echo mime_content_type($img_path);
   ```
2. finfo function

   ```
   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
   echo finfo_file($finfo, $img_path);
   finfo_close($finfo);
   ```

But I am getting error for both the cases

**"Warning: finfo_file(): Failed identify data 0:no magic files loaded"**

I am not getting what is the issue in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like $img_path is not containing any file or wrong file path.

Comment: yeah, There was an issue with a path. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

For people wondering in the future, the original poster probably had an external URL set as the path - both the "mime_content_type" & "finfo" functions can only be ran on **local paths** and not external URLS.

Example:

```
// Local file path
echo mime_content_type("image.gif");
```

Will return: image/gif

```
// External file path
echo mime_content_type("http://localhost/image.gif");
```

Will return "Warning: mime_content_type(): Failed identify data 0:no magic files loaded"

Fallback versions and more information on usage of these functions can be found in the manual on PHP.net:
mime_content_type:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

finfo functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php

Comment: Yes,It's work with **local paths** and not external URLS